# println(currentWeatherDictionary) function not working

Tags: ios, swift

***Here is my code: the println(currentWeatherDictionary) should print out the weather for those coordinates from that URL, but it prints out nothing, is it a problem with xcode? Im using xcode 6.01***

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Replace the string below with your API Key.
    private let apiKey = "d22b3b492d25282da275e826cc50757b"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let baseURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/\(apiKey)/")
        let forecastURL = NSURL(string: "43.067827,-77.541085", relativeToURL: baseURL)


        let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(forecastURL!, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {
                let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)
                let weatherDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary


                let currentWeatherDictionary: NSDictionary = weatherDictionary["currently"] as NSDictionary

                println(currentWeatherDictionary)

            }

        })

        downloadTask.resume()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for your `println(currentWeatherDictionary)` line to be executed and not print anything. Make sure that `error` is not `nil` and that the completion handler is being called. You can do so with either breakpoints or additional `println` statements.